# jquery image slider modification

Tags: jquery, slider

Am trying to modify a piece of code below so that the fadeout function doesn't happen. I want the next image to fadeIn over the existing image. Can anyone help as I've tried removing the fadeOut function and it doesn't work.

```
$(function () {

    var changeTime = 5000;
    var speed = 1500;

    var slider = $("#imageSlide"),
        listItems = slider.children('li'),
        listLen = listItems.length,
        i = 0,

        changeList = function () {

            listItems.eq(i).fadeOut(speed, function () {
                i += 1;
                if (i === listLen) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(speed);
            });

        };

    listItems.not(':first').hide();
    setInterval(changeList, changeTime);

});
```

css I have is:

```
#imageSlide {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
ul#imageSlide {
list-style:none;
list-style-image:none;
margin-left:0px;
}
li#imageSlide {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

HTML Markup is:

```
<ul id="imageSlide">
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/image1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/image2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/image3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/image4.jpg" /></li>
<li><img alt="" src="/Images/image5.jpg" /></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove `fadeOut` like this

```
$(function () {

var changeTime = 5000;
var speed = 1500;

var slider = $("#imageSlide"),
    listItems = slider.children('li'),
    listLen = listItems.length,
    i = 0,

    changeList = function () {
        i += 1;
        if (i === listLen) {
            i = 0;
        }
        listItems.eq(i).fadeIn(speed);
    };

listItems.not(':first').hide();
setInterval(changeList, changeTime);

});
```

Comment: Yes - the images fadeIn below each image rather than on top .

Comment: Then the problem is connected to CSS. That is completely other question. But if you'll update your question with some HTML markup and CSS I'll fix it for you.

Comment: Thank you - Sorry I'm new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working have you **included** any `jquery version` in your page

See working [Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/jVjaR) and [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/jVjaR/1/) and [Demo3](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/jVjaR/2/)

And [Demo4](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/jVjaR/4/) without **fadeOut**

Comment: Thanks but I need the fadeIN to happen on its own, not with the fadeOut

Comment: thanks - its almost there, the fadeIn needs to happen over the existing image not removed then fadeIn.